# Can the Simulacrum of a Level 10+ Cleric attempt a Divine Intervention?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, divine

Clerics get the Divine Intervention feature at level 10.

> Beginning at 10th level, you can call on your deity to intervene on your behalf as an action. Describe the assistance you seek, and roll percentile dice. If you roll a number equal to or lower than your cleric level, your deity intervenes. The DM chooses the nature of the intervention.
>
> If your deity intervenes, you can't use this feature again for 7 days. Otherwise, you can use it again after you finish a long rest.
>
> At 20th level, your call for intervention succeeds automatically, no roll required.

If someone makes a Simulacrum of a Level 10+ Cleric, can that Simulacrum attempt a Divine Intervention ?

Comment: I think there are game balance issues here which are not addressed by the linked question.  If I'm level 20 and my divine intervention automatically succeeds, does this mean every simulacrum can request a new divine intervention, bypassing the one-per-week limit?

Comment: -- and, does this work for *wish* too?  ie, can my simulacrum cast *wish* for me, losing the ability to cast *wish* ever again, so that I don't have to eat that penalty?